# How to get Auto generated key in JPA by using @Query?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, hierarchy

is there any way to get the auto generated primary key by using query.

```
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "Insert into device_menu(MenuName,ICON,Type,TenantID,ParentID) Values (:menuName,:icon,:type,:tenantId,:parentId)", nativeQuery = true)
    int createMenu(@Param("menuName") String name, @Param("icon") String icon, @Param("type") int type,
            @Param("tenantId") int tenantId, @Param("parentId") int parentId);
```

below is the entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "deviceMenu")
public class Menu {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "menu_id")
private int id;

@NotBlank
private int parentId;
@NotBlank
private int type;
private String menuName;
private String iconURL;
@Column(name = "form_uuid")
private String formUUID;
private String searchId;
private byte IsActive;
@Column(name = "tenant_id")
private int tenantId;
@NotBlank
private int sortOrder;
private String[] formList;
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "device_menu_privilege", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "menu_id", referencedColumnName = "menu_id"))
private int[] roleId;
```

i m not using Entity Manager Or predefined method because i have to store the data in selected columns only and also i have to implement hierarchical nested objects like this

```
{
  "menuId": 1,
  "menuName": "Inspection",
  "icon": "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/front-man/beta/170b090b-1424-4c78-8def-e57d39436a27/DeviceMenu/185febd1-f2b8-4d39-b3a2-f5dd0e6be40c.png",
  "type": 1,
  "formId": 0,
  "formUUID": null,
  "formName": null,
  "parentId": 0,
  "menu": [
    {
      "menuId": 440,
      "menuName": null,
      "icon": null,
      "type": 2,
      "formId": 0,
      "formUUID": "2f84a801-cc3e-4807-a68c-cdd3cc9df9af",
      "formName": "Production Line",
      "parentId": 1,
      "menu": [
        {
          "menuId": 450,
          "menuName": null,
          "icon": null,
          "type": 2,
          "formId": 0,
          "formUUID": "41e8e326-000a-4d8a-abb6-ece29b80a9c5",
          "formName": "Inspection Form",
          "parentId": 3,
          "menu": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understan why don't you use the predifined `save` method. In both cases (that one, and yours) the columns not informed will be saved with a null value.

Anyway, ¿Have you tried to return the Entity instead of int?

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "Insert into device_menu(MenuName,ICON,Type,TenantID,ParentID) Values (:menuName,:icon,:type,:tenantId,:parentId)", nativeQuery = true)
Menu createMenu(@Param("menuName") String name, @Param("icon") String icon, @Param("type") int type,
        @Param("tenantId") int tenantId, @Param("parentId") int parentId);
```

Comment: can you please explain me, how can i implement by using save/persist method for the hierarchical nested menu?

Comment: If you have created the FK in parentId correctly, I would create the Entity with Hibernate Tools (you have and example here, and lots of them inside stackoverflow http://www.tech-freaks.com/jsp-servlets/jboss-reverse-engineer-hibernate.html). But this is not mandatory.

The thing is that, in your entity, parentId should be of Menu type, not int. And then, you just can save an Entity (with save method), or a list of Entities (saveAll method). The differencewould be that in some cases parentId will have a value (if they are children) or not (if they are parent).